# How to control and reset counter value in below python code?

Tags: python

I have written following code that extracts Capital letters, symbols and rename the directories. adding suffix _counter if already directory exists. Counter has to reset and add suffix for every fresh directory. How do we control it?

```
    import os
    folder_path = r'D:\c1\a\\'
    count = 1
    temp = os.walk(folder_path,topdown=False)
    for root, dirs, files in temp:
        for i in dirs:
            source = os.path.join(root, i)
            Upper_chars = ''.join(x for x in i if not x.islower())
            if len(Upper_chars) > 1:
                try:
                    Destination = os.path.join(root, Upper_chars)
                    os.rename(source, Destination)
                except FileExistsError:
                    Destination = os.path.join(root, Upper_chars+'_'+str(count))
                    os.rename(source, Destination)
                    count = count +1
    
    print('All Directories Renamed')
```

Comment: At the beginning of the loop over the dirs set count to 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another approach might be using a while loop and increment the counter until the folder doesn't exists.

```
count = 1
while os.path.exists(Destination):
    # if path exists, this will keep looping and incrementing the counter
    Destination = Destination + '_' + str(count)
    count += 1
```

Full code is here:

```
import os

folder_path = r"E:\\"
temp = os.walk(folder_path, topdown=False)
for root, dirs, files in temp:
    for i in dirs:
        source = os.path.join(root, i)

        Upper_chars = ''.join(x for x in i if x.isupper())
        if len(Upper_chars) > 1:
            Destination = os.path.join(root, Upper_chars)

            count = 1
            while os.path.exists(Destination):
                Destination = Destination + '_' + str(count)
                count += 1

            os.rename(source, Destination)

print('All Directories Renamed')
```

BTW.. you can just use `isupper()` instead of `not islower()`

Comment: Thank you. If i execute the script again, it renames all the files, How do we avoid this kind of scenario?

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to move reset your counter, you can reset it after it has completed the last loop prior to moving to the next directory or just after the you start the directory. Either will have the same effect.

From your code either:

```
import os
folder_path = r'D:\c1\a\\'
temp = os.walk(folder_path,topdown=False)
for root, dirs, files in temp:
    for i in dirs:
        count = 1
        source = os.path.join(root, i)
        Upper_chars = ''.join(x for x in i if not x.islower())
        if len(Upper_chars) > 1:
            try:
                Destination = os.path.join(root, Upper_chars)
                os.rename(source, Destination)
            except FileExistsError:
                Destination = os.path.join(root, Upper_chars+'_'+str(count))
                os.rename(source, Destination)
                count = count +1
```

OR

```
import os
folder_path = r'D:\c1\a\\'
count = 1
temp = os.walk(folder_path,topdown=False)
for root, dirs, files in temp:
    for i in dirs:
        source = os.path.join(root, i)
        Upper_chars = ''.join(x for x in i if not x.islower())
        if len(Upper_chars) > 1:
            try:
                Destination = os.path.join(root, Upper_chars)
                os.rename(source, Destination)
            except FileExistsError:
                Destination = os.path.join(root, Upper_chars+'_'+str(count))
                os.rename(source, Destination)
                count = count +1
        count = 1
```

Comment: the identation for your `count = 1` at the end of your loop is messed up, you need to keep that `count` in the first `for` not within the second

Comment: I think what you mean is the indentation is ugly in the second.  It is not incorrect in either the first or the second.  In the second it is the last line to run prior to going back up to the  `for i in dirs`, which has the same effect as setting it to one at the right after he starts examining the i-s in dirs. Even the accepted answer recognizes that the appropriate point to reset the counter is *within* the second for